# Need help on JTable, Changing cell color

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

```
public static void setCellRenderer(JTable CustDtlsTbl) {
    TableCellRenderer cellRenderer = createCellRenderer();
    CustDtlsTbl.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, cellRenderer);
}
```

...

```
public static TableCellRenderer createCellRenderer() {
return new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable CustDtlsTbl, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {  
        Component cell =  super.getTableCellRendererComponent(CustDtlsTbl, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
```

How to modify the above two methods to change cell color when the value is negative?

Comment: Well you need an if condition to test if the value is negative then you set the background. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem if you can't get it to work.

Comment: The `static` modifiers are a hint the code is doing it wrong..

Comment: I've added this :    if ( column == 1 ) {                
                  cell.setForeground(Color.RED);
            } else {
                cell.setForeground(Color.BLACK); 
            }      but i need to check that if the cell value negative also, how to do that pls?